# Qt Android notification, Cannot set image

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I am making an Android testapp in Qt using Java libraries for the notifications. Following the Qt Notifier example im trying recreate the same notification for starters but for some reason this line does not work:

```
m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

it says:

```
java:77: error: error: package R does not exist
```

I have tried adding:

```
import java.lang.Object;
import android.R.drawable;
```

I have also tried:

```
m_builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.icon);
```

but this gives me the error:

```
java:77: error: error: cannot find symbol
```

So I have checked the Qt Notifier app and I dont think i have made any mistakes but for some reason it won't work.

**My question is: How do I set this icon correctly?**

Here is the full piece of code:

```
package org.qtproject.qt5.example;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.Throwable;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.R.drawable;


public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
    private static NotificationClient m_instance;

    public NotificationClient()
    {
        try {
            m_instance = this;
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void notify(String s)
    {
        try {
            if (m_notificationManager == null) {
                m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
                m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
                //m_builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.icon);
            }

            m_builder.setContentText(s);
            m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());

        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error make sure that package name in your java class and your AndroidManifest.xml are the same.

NotificationClient.java:

```
package com.mypackage;
...
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest package="com.mypackage"...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was because of a wrong configuration in AndroidManifest.xml.

After editing the AndroidManifest correctly and cleaning and rebuilding the project, the problem was solved.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem. It is important that after you fix the package name, you need to remove the build outputs completilly and rebuild. Running clean doesnt fix the problem.